# How to make an install script run just once in Travis CI

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, github-pages

I have set up my [GitHub pages](https://github.com/monteva/monteva.github.io/). It is made using [gitfolio](https://github.com/imfunniee/gitfolio).

I have also set up [Travis CI](https://github.com/monteva/monteva.github.io/blob/master/.travis.yml) to automatically update the details of the website. Here is my `before_script`.

```
before_script:
  - git clone https://github.com/imfunniee/gitfolio.git
  - cd gitfolio
  - npm install
```

This script clones the gitfolio repo every single time a build is started. However, I want Travis CI to clone the repo only once and not every single time. This is because I want to make some changes the the cloned git repo and since I am cloning the repo again and again, none of my changes persist.

Is there any way for me to clone the git repo just once, make changes to the cloned repo, and then just never have to git clone again?

Answer (score 0):

Travis is launching a fresh instance on every build so your changes will not persist.

You could try to use [cache on travis side](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) but I doubt it will exactly suit your needs in this situation. You would anyway have to rely on the cache, check if the directory exists and clone only if it doesn't. You would also have to implement a pull strategy to get the latest changes and that might get tricky if you keep uncommitted changes. Give it a try and see.

A much better option IMO is to continue to clone as you do (although I would consider using the `--depth` parameter to speed up operations), then make your changes and commit them back to a specific repo/branch. You then just have to `git clone -b specificBranch` to get your persisted changes.